# Homework2.hs: checking that the beneficiary signed the transaction

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Spoiler, so don't look if you haven't done the homework yet.

In the solution file Solution2.hs we have

```
checkSig :: Bool
checkSig = unPaymentPubKeyHash pkh `elem` txInfoSignatories info
```

while in the file from the lecture Vesting.hs we have the same check implemented as

```
signedByBeneficiary :: Bool
signedByBeneficiary = txSignedBy info $ unPaymentPubKeyHash $ beneficiary dat
```

I get the same behavior in the playground with the two implementations in Solution2.hs, and moreover looking at the implementation of txSignedBy

```
{-# INLINABLE txSignedBy #-}
-- | Check if a transaction was signed by the given public key.
txSignedBy :: TxInfo -> PubKeyHash -> Bool
txSignedBy TxInfo{txInfoSignatories} k = case find ((==) k) txInfoSignatories of
    Just _  -> True
    Nothing -> False
```

I don't see a difference. Maybe my tests in the playground aren't good enough, but is there an example of different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. I'd say the `signedByBeneficiary` way is more idiomatic.